# How to use HAProxy with web socket RabbitMQ's Web MQTT and add SSL/TLS?

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, haproxy, paho

I am struggling to make HAProxy work with RabbitMQ's Web MQTT (MQTT via Web Socket). I tried some configurations and tutorials but had no success ([haproxy blog](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/), [BartKrol Github](https://gist.github.com/BartKrol/bdf344ac26c25b0234bc), [s0urcec0de's Github](https://gist.github.com/sourcec0de/0834e50e0470e573419f979597c701c8)). Also tried setting HAProxy and [RabbitMQ with Proxy Protocol](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#proxy-protocol) with no success.

I really want to use HAProxy on this, but I am having a hard time with it.

My intention is to use a Javascript Paho MQTT client in the browser to connect to RabbitMQ Web Socket MQTT broker and between them HAProxy will be encryption http/ws connections with TLS/SSL certificates provided (also called SSL/TLS offloading).

When trying to open the secure websocket connection with HAProxy, the browser gets a HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable response

RabbitMQ Server is listening for unencrypted websocket mqtt connections at localhost:15675

HAProxy is listening at ws.mydomain.io:3001

This is the HAProxy configuration:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1 local0

        defaults
                log global
                option httplog
                timeout client 5000s
                timeout connect 5000s
                timeout queue 5000s
                timeout server 5000s

frontend https
        bind *:3001 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/mydomain.io.pem
        mode http
        log                     global
        backlog                 4096

        default_backend web_mqtt

backend web_mqtt
        mode http
        option forwardfor

        server ws_01 localhost:15675
```

I tried to achieve the same configuration with Nginx **and it worked successfully** [(configuration based on their official documentation)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html).

Nginx is listening at ws.mydomain.io:3000

```
  server {
    listen 3000 ssl;
    server_name ws.mydomain.io;

    ssl_certificate /home/tiago/Keys/mydomain/nginx/mydomain.io.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/tiago/Keys/mydomain/nginx/mydomain.io.key;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://ws-backend;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }

  upstream ws-backend {
    # enable sticky session based on IP
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:15675;
  }
```

RabbitMQ's configuration (rabbitmq.conf):

```
log.connection.level = info
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672

# proxy_protocol = true

web_mqtt.tcp.port = 15675
```

What am I missing in the HAProxy configuration?

How can Nginx proxy the request and HAProxy not?

The setup:

- Debian 10 x64
- HAProxy 2.1.3
- Javascript Paho MQTT Client 1.1.0
- Nginx 1.14.2
- RabbitMQ 3.8.3

This is the response after the secure websocket connection attempt with Paho MQTT lib in Firefox:

```
GET
https://ws.mydomain.io:3001/ws
[HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 3027ms]

Request URL:https://ws.mydomain.io:3001/ws
Request method:GET
Remote address:127.0.0.1:3001
Status code:
503
Version:HTTP/1.1

Response headers (126 B)    
Raw headers
cache-control   
no-cache
connection  
close
content-length  
107
content-type    
text/html
Request headers (484 B) 
Raw headers
Accept  
*/*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   
no-cache
Connection  
keep-alive, Upgrade
Host    
ws.mydomain.io:3001
Origin  
http://localhost:8123
Pragma  
no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions    
permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key   
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol  
mqtt
Sec-WebSocket-Version   
13
Upgrade 
websocket
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
```

This is firefox message:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://ws.mydomain.io:3001/ws.
```

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem.
I'm not that familiar with haproxy to tell you, what you have done wrong. 
But i can share you my configuration which is working. 
The backend `be_mqtt_www` is never used, so maybe it would not be necessary.

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base <path_to_certs>
        crt-base <path_to_certs>

        # See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        option  redispatch
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


# proxy for ui
frontend ft_rabbitmq_https
        bind *:443 ssl crt <path_to_cert>
        mode http
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        option httpchk
        default_backend bk_rabbitmq_ui

backend bk_rabbitmq_ui
        server localhost 127.0.0.1:15672 check

# proxy for mqtt-tls
listen mqtt
        bind *:8883 ssl crt <path_to_cert>
        mode tcp
        option clitcpka
        timeout client 3h
        timeout server 3h
        option tcplog
        server localhost 127.0.0.1:1883 check

#proxy for tls-websockets
frontend fe_mqtt_wss
        bind *:9001 ssl crt <path_to_cert>
        mode http
        option http-server-close
        acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
        use_backend be_mqtt_ws if is_websocket
        default_backend be_mqtt_www

backend be_mqtt_ws
        timeout server 600s
        server localhost 127.0.0.1:15675/ws check

backend be_mqtt_www
        timeout server 600s
        server localhost 127.0.0.1:15675 check
```

Comment: Which version of HAProxy are you using?
Did you configure any global or default on your haproxy.cfg file?
I'm getting a fatal error with your example.
I had to insert "mode http" in all backends for HAProxy be able to start, but the proxy still doesn't work.

Comment: I am using HA-Proxy version 2.1.3.

yes, sorry they are default configs. i added them in my answer.